# How to modify a Google Sheets script to change a comma (as separator) into a new line?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, separator, carriage-return

I have a Google Sheets script that allows me to pick several options from a drop-down menu. However, the script writes the result is the cell with each value separated with a comma while I need a new line for each option selected.
The code is as follows:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
  .addToUi();
}
function showDialog() {  
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showSidebar(html);
}
var valid = function(){
  try{
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues();
  }catch(e){
    return null
  }
}
function fillCell(e){
  var s = [];
  for(var i in e){
    if(i.substr(0, 2) == 'ch') s.push(e[i]);
  }
  if(s.length) SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(s.join(', '));
}
```

I changed in the last line, `s.join(', ')` into `s.join(vbNewLine)` or `s.join(chr(10))` with no success. This is the result I get:

[image: Values separated by commas]

and this is what I need:

[image]

I do not know how to script Google Sheets code, but I need to modify this one. How can I change the code to make the separator to be a carriage return instead of a comma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
s.join('\n')
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks, Warcupine for edit the wrong scripting language.